# Add the chapter word in 90 degree rotation with fanchdr

Tags: sectioning, chapters

I apologize if my question may seem inconceivable.

I want to replace the blue rectangle that contains the chapter number

[image: image1]

in this [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122759/how-to-obtain-this-fancy-chapter-page-with-the-book-class), with this one

[image: image2]

in this [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159485/huge-ornament-chapter-numbering) by keeping the chapter word with the rotation of 90 degree.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: This has nothing to do with fancyhdr.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, one can combine the two answers in the way you suggest. If you have questions on specific parts of the code please feel free to ask. The only thing I added to the answers is to add a `local bounding box` around the ornament that allows one to easily position the rotated `Chapter`.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfornament}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{0,0,122}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\huge\bfseries\raggedleft}
  {\begin{tikzpicture}
   \begin{scope}[local bounding box=orna]
    \node[text width=3cm,align=center] (chapnum)
      {\fontsize{100}{130}\color{gray}\selectfont\thechapter};%
    \node[shift={(-1cm,1cm)},anchor=north west](CNW)
      at (chapnum.north west) {\pgfornament[width=1.75cm]{61}};
    \node[shift={(1cm,1cm)},anchor=north east](CNE)
      at (chapnum.north east) {\pgfornament[width=1.75cm,symmetry=v]{61}};
    \node[shift={(-1cm,-1cm)},anchor=south west](CSW)
      at (chapnum.south west) {\pgfornament[width=1.75cm,symmetry=h]{61}};
    \node[shift={(1cm,-1cm)},anchor=south east](CSE)
      at (chapnum.south east) {\pgfornament[width=1.75cm,symmetry=c]{61}};
   \end{scope}  
   \node[rotate=90,anchor=south,inner sep=0pt,font=\Huge\sffamily] at (orna.west) {\chaptertitlename};  
  \end{tikzpicture}
  }{0pt}{\fontsize{33}{40}\selectfont\color{myblue}#1}[\vskip10pt\Large]
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{50pt}{10pt}


\begin{document}


\chapter{Test chapter}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for your precious help!